# How parameter.method() method works?

Tags: java, string

Well, i was thinking about that kind of methods.
They dont recive parameters, but they work with them.

An example: `.replace(Char, Char)`  of String API, it works with a String followed by a dot.

Like:

```
String test = "= Text = without = equals";
String output = test.replace("=","");
```

How it works without  receive the parameter test?
I'm just being curious, want to do a method like these.

Sorry for my bad english!
Thanks.

Comment: It seems you are thinking `test` as parameter, which is not the case, it just an object which is calling its string class method

Comment: Well, i mean this don't receive the parameter like `replace(test, "=","");`

Comment: Buy a basic java book. It will tell you how member functions work. Even a Learn Java in 10 minutes kind of book will cover this. This topic will probably be covered somewhere in between 2nd and 3rd minute.

Comment: So you call String class method with your variable test? 
But it change the content of the String.

Comment: "replace(test, "=","");" is like writing "this.replace(test, "=","");"

Comment: Don't think of it as `String` _class_ method, think of it as `String` _instance_ method. Also, **it doesn't change the content of the String, because String is immutable**. It returns a new String object, with the changes applied.

Comment: well, Thanks!
Now i understand it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you build a new type of String, that only does replace stuff (why not?!):

```
public class MyString {
    private final String s;
    public MyString(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }
    public String replace(String search, String replace) {
        return s.replace(search, replace);
    }
}
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
MyString myString = new MyString("= Text = without = equals");
String output = myString.replace("=", "");
```

Et voila, you have done the same "trick"! And you can see how it works: your `MyString` object keeps some data internally (the `s` variable) and can access that data from its methods.

Comment: Thanks!
Now i see how it works! 

Sorry if it was a "Noob" question!

Answer (score 0):

These are [instance methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html), which means that they require an instantiated class object to operate. So, the string class knows the value of `test` in your example, because it has access to the instantiated data.

To create these types of methods, simply define them within your class and do not mark them as static.

Answer (score 0):

String is an object. The class definition is part of the Java standard library. That definition includes the `replace` method.

Since String is a `final` class you can not subclass it to add additional methods. So you can not do what you are trying to do.